# VSCode Extension Pack for Java error "Corrupt ZIP"

Tags: java

I can't install Extension Pack for Java on VSCode and I am getting these errors:

```
[2021-11-10 18:56:43.703] [renderer1] [info] Starting extension host with pid 12456.
[2021-11-10 18:56:43.704] [renderer1] [info] [LocalProcessExtensionHost]: IExtensionHostStarter.start() took 66 ms.
[2021-11-10 18:56:44.709] [renderer1] [error] [Extension Host] (node:12456) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
(Use `Code --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
[2021-11-10 18:59:52.758] [renderer1] [error] ["Internal: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found","    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17804","    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)","    at v (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17790)","    at O.joinAllSettled (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:10128)","    at async O.installExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:7649)"]
[2021-11-10 18:59:52.800] [renderer1] [error] Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found: Internal: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17804
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at v (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17790)
    at O.joinAllSettled (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:10128)
    at async O.installExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:7649)
[2021-11-10 19:02:30.434] [renderer1] [error] ["Internal: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found","    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17804","    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)","    at v (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17790)","    at O.joinAllSettled (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:10128)","    at async O.installExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:7649)"]
[2021-11-10 19:02:30.475] [renderer1] [error] Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found: Internal: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17804
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at v (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17790)
    at O.joinAllSettled (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:10128)
    at async O.installExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:7649)
[2021-11-10 19:02:44.917] [renderer1] [error] ["Invalid: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found","    at q.downloadInstallableExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:200682)","    at async q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:199396)"]
[2021-11-10 19:02:44.948] [renderer1] [error] Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found: Invalid: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at q.downloadInstallableExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:200682)
    at async q.doRun (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:199396)
[2021-11-10 19:03:21.645] [renderer1] [error] ["Internal: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found","    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17804","    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)","    at v (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17790)","    at O.joinAllSettled (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:10128)","    at async O.installExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:7649)"]
[2021-11-10 19:03:21.707] [renderer1] [error] Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found: Internal: Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found,Corrupt ZIP: end of central directory record signature not found
    at vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17804
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at v (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:17790)
    at O.joinAllSettled (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:10128)
    at async O.installExtension (vscode-file://vscode-app/c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft%20VS%20Code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:48:7649)
```

Does anyone know why I'm getting the Corrupt ZIP error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the file downloaded is corrupted. Please try to remove the related extension files in `$HOME/.vscode/extensions/` and try to install again.

Comment: still getting the same error. I have even done a fresh install of VSCode yet I keep getting this message.